# UIButton image always to be 80 point away from title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have used this method to set image 80 point away from title. Button has blue color background here.

```
    self.btnErrorMsg.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 80);
```

[image]

Problem is if the text is longer, it overlap with text. How shall I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Use :

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat left, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat right);
```

it Works for me perfectly

Comment: If text is dynamic (super long or super short), it is not okay.